# Selecting data assistance

Tags: sql

I'm trying to display two sets of data. The first set shows the people that own complexes that have tenants in them. The second set shows people that own complexes that do not have any tenants in them.

This is the full list of complex names:

```
COMPN
-----
CM700
CM350
CM300
CM600
CM900
CM200
CM100
```

I figured out how to filter out the ones that currently have rental agreements. I used the following command.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT customer.custlname,
                customer.custfname
FROM customer,
     own,
     rental
WHERE own.custid = customer.custid
  AND rental.compname = own.compname;
```

Then I get the following result:

```
CUSTLNAME  CUSTFNAME
---------- ----------
Pearson    Robert
Garnet     Kylie
Agassi     Pamela
```

This corresponds to these values:

```
COMPN
-----
CM350
CM900
CM200
```

I am now trying to figure out how to display the people that do not have tenants in their complexes. I'm not exactly sure how to approach this. I've been messing with it for a while and I can't quite figure out the correct operator procedure to use.

Thanks

Additional Information about tables:

Customer

```
CUSTID CUSTLNAME  CUSTFNAME  BDATE     S MGR
```

CUSTID is the PK.

Own:

```
CUSTID COMPNAME
```

CUSTID is a FK referring to table Customer.
COMPNAME is a FK referring to table Complex.

Rental:

```
CUSTID COMPNAME   APTNUM
```

CUSTID is the FK referring to table Customer.
COMPNAME is a FK referring to table Complex.
APTNUM is a FK referring to table apartment.

Comment: @Luv I'm not sure I understand what you need. Do you mean the PK and FK and what tables exist or what exactly?

Comment: @Luv The query does not appear to work for me. Changing it to a not null, produces the same results as above. I'm going to look and see if my original query design is adequate.

Comment: Please provide **column name** of the above mentioned **tables**. And i will give you the perfect Query. **:)**

Comment: @Luv I added the additional relevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>From the **current information**</s>

```
select distinct customer.custlname, customer.custfname
from customer
left join own on own.custid = customer.custid
inner join rental on rental.compname = own.compname
where own.custid is null
```

**Edit: 1**

***how to display the people that do not have tenants in their complexes***

Use **NOT IN**

The below Query will give me the **COMPNAME** where there are **No Tenants**

```
select Complex.COMPNAME
from Complex,
Where COMPNAME NOT IN
(select COMPNAME
from rental)
```

**Edit 2:**

According to **OP** ***wish list***

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer.custlname,
                customer.custfname
FROM customer,
     own,
     rental
WHERE own.custid = customer.custid
AND rental.compname = own.compname
AND rental.compname in (select Complex.COMPNAME
                        from Complex,
                        Where COMPNAME NOT IN
                        (select COMPNAME
                        from rental))
```

Comment: This query does correctly show the empty complexes correctly. This is really a beginning project for me. So, how would I correctly nest this query?

Comment: i didn't get the **statment** i.e. ***how would I correctly nest this query?***

Comment: I meant, how would I use the IN command to place your code into a statement similar to mine (shown above).

Comment: Run the `Query` in **Edit 2:** and let me know if it solved your **Problem**